# fancy box works locally with jekyll but not on github

Tags: github, jekyll, fancybox-2

Just installed Jekyll and got a site up and running. You can see it here: [`http://nielsrasmus.github.io/sunset.html`](http://nielsrasmus.github.io/sunset.html).

Everything works perfectly except that I can't get [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to work on GitHub.

I've downloaded and implemented the latest code from [`fancyapps.com`](http://fancyapps.com).

It works fine locally, on `localhost:4000`, so I assume that I didn't make any errors.
So the problem must be that GitHub rejects the JavaScript code?

How do I make fancyBox work as expected when hosted on GitHub?

Comment: I deleted my answer which assumed fancyBox was a Jekyll plugin that was trying to be run on the GitHub Pages server. That's not the case. The site was being built locally but had a typo in it. @user3137811, If you'll post an answer with what you did and accept it, it'll help others out who may run into the same issue.

Comment: Sorry. Did write it but Apparently I was cut of before posting :-/
But you are right, it was a typo in the href path.
the link said "fancybox" but should have been "fancyBox" (capital B).
There's a difference between the provided links and the name of the dir in the downloaded zip file.